# Python3 Selenium ChromeDriver Disable Extensions Logging Only Pyinstaller Windows 10

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

[image]

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.5.4, Windows Chrome Driver 2.33 and Selnium 3.6.0 and Pyinstaller 3.3.

My Chrome Driver extensions produce logging to the console which looks to be cause caused by the extensions in Chrome.

*(I have tried with chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions") and the logging was not evident)*

I want to **keep** using the Chrome Extensions however I just want to ***disable this logging.***

Until I can disable this logging I cannot create a pyinstaller.exe without a console.

Any suggestions on how to disable selenium chrome driver extension logging only? Or a work around in Python to play nice with pyinstaller to create the exe without a console?

Thanks for your time.

```
# Python Script Parameters for chrome driver.

# example.py

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\testuser\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: same problem here. i haven't found how to disable it yet

Answer (score 1):

If you want disable console you should modife source code of webdriver file service.py. Example path to file `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py`
Change from **line 69** to this.

```
try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())

        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env, startupinfo=startupinfo,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
    except TypeError:
        raise
```

Then, when you built your app and run, Chromedriver console will not show up.